# check whether the string is palindrome or not

Tags: c, string, function, stack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int checkpalindrome(char* a,int n);
int main()
{
    char *a;
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter the size of the string but should be odd => ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a=(char*)calloc(n,sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==(n-1)/2)
        {  printf("Enter X\n");}
        scanf("%c",&a[i]);
    }
    if(checkpalindrome(a,n)){
      printf("\nstring is palindrome");
    }
    else{ 
      printf("\nstring is not a palindrome");
    }
    return 0;
}
int checkpalindrome(char *a,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[n-i])
          continue;
        else
          return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

check this code i am not getting proper output 
here the string should be of a's and b's and X should in middle of the string and we have to check whether the string is palindrome or not.

Comment: Have you looked at your string before testing its palindromicity? The way you use `scanf`, odds are that your actual string starts with a new-line character.

Comment: Unrelated, `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` in `checkpalindrome` is overkill. You're needlessly checking literally twice the number of slots as needed. The entire sequence is covered with `n/2` iterations (think about why).

Comment: @Nayan Gupta Wjat is this          if(i==(n-1)/2)
        {  printf("Enter X\n");} doing in the program?

Comment: sir , M Oehm what the problem with the string can you pls tell i am not getting it .

Comment: @Vlad sir If(i==(n-1)/2){printf("Enter X\n");}  this to enter character X in the middle of string

Comment: just to acknowlage user to input X

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement two stacks in a single array then you will need to divide the SIZE of the initialized array by 2. Then you have to distinguish the two stacks with these basic initialization.

```
int stack[9], SIZE, max1, max2, top1, top2;
SIZE = 10;
max1 = (SIZE/2) - 1; 
max2 = SIZE - 1;
top1 = -1;
top2 = max1;
```

so by doing this, they are totally separated.
so you should have two push methods push1() and push2 and two pop methods pop1() and pop2() separately written in accordance to the respective stack parameters.